# ploting markers in python

Tags: python, pandas

i am using pandas, and filling a data frame with some data... i want to plot the data in a graph and plot markers on it (signals)

i have this code:

```
data_frame.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)  # set Datetime column as index
plt.plot(data_frame['close'])
plt.plot(data_frame['long'].index, data_frame['close'], '^', markersize=2, color='g')
plt.plot(data_frame['short'].index, data_frame['close'], '^', markersize=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

`data_frame['long']` and `data_frame['short']` are bool values (True or False), `data_frame['close']` is close price (float)

the result:

[image: chart]

Ploting is happening even if `data_frame['long']/data_frame['short']` is false

Comment: Could you explain more and perhaps give what your expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop thru data and check if the data is true or false:

```
for idx in data_frame["long"].index.tolist():
    if data_frame.loc[idx]["long"]:
        plt.plot(idx, data_frame.loc[idx]["close"], "^", markersize=5, color="g")
```